# pandas loc function refers to different row when writing vs. reading -> ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

When running the example code below I get a

```
ValueError: cannot set using a multi-index selection indexer with a different
length than the value
```

The error is raised upon execution of

```
df.loc[(9, 0), ("clouds", "type")] = np.array([None, None])
```

here:

```
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _setitem_with_indexer(self, indexer, value)
    492 
    493                     if len(obj[idx]) != len(value):
--> 494                         raise ValueError
```

The problem seems to be connected to writing a numpy array to a "cell" of the dataframe. It seems that `obj[idx]` refers to index (20,) in the dataframe, while it should refer to (9,0). A few iterations before the one that raises the error, when executing

```
df.loc[(6, 0), ("clouds", "type")] = np.array([None, None])
```

no error is raised as by coincidence `obj[idx]` refers to index (17,) in the dataframe which has 2 sub-indices, so that by chance `len(obj[idx])==len(value)==2`.

Remark:

When I read

```
df.loc[(9, 0), ("clouds", "type")].values
```

it correctly returns `[104]`.

### Question:

Am I using the `.loc` function incorrectly? Am I doing something else wrong? Or is this a problem within pandas? How could I avoid it?

I greatly appreciate any help as the problem got me stuck for a few days now :/

### Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

mi = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
                           [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]],
                   labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 12, 13, 14, 14,
                            14, 15, 16, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22],
                           [0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0,
                            0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]])


mc = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['clouds', 'group', 'header', 'vertical_visibility', 'visibility', 'weather', 'wind', 'windshear'],
                           ['', 'BR', 'DS', 'DU', 'DZ', 'FC', 'FG', 'FU', 'GR', 'GS', 'HZ', 'IC', 'PL', 'PO', 'PY', 'RA', 'SA', 'SG', 'SN', 'SQ', 'SS', 'UP', 'VA', 'altitude', 'ceiling', 'direction', 'form', 'from_date', 'from_hours', 'from_minutes', 'gust', 'icao_code', 'layer', 'more', 'origin_date', 'origin_hours', 'origin_minutes', 'probability', 'range', 'speed', 'till_date', 'till_hours', 'till_minutes', 'type', 'unit', 'valid_from_date', 'valid_from_hours', 'valid_till_date', 'valid_till_hours'],
                           ['bool', 'intensity', 'modifier']],
                   labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                           [24, 32, 43, 27, 28, 29],
                           [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]])

arr = np.array(range(0,len(mi)*len(mc))).reshape(len(mi),len(mc))

df = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=mi, columns=mc)


values = {0: {0: [None]}, 1: {0: [None], 1: [None], 2: [None], 3: [None]}, 2: {0: [None], 2: [None]}, 3: {0: [None], 1: [None], 2: [None], 3: [None], 4: [None], 5: [None]}, 4: {0: [None]}, 6: {0: [None, None]}, 9: {0: [None, None]}}


for i, val in values.items():
    for j, v in val.items():
        df.loc[(i,j),("clouds", "type")] = np.array(v)
```

Comment: Is it really your intention to use this loop-of-loops to insert a bunch of NumPy arrays containing [None, None] or similar into a DataFrame?  This is very unusual and suggests a design problem.

Comment: Thanks for your remark! What I am trying to do is to fit weather forecast objects (~100 million of them) as efficiently as possible into a dataframe. To save memory I wanted to conver e. g. the "cloud type" element of each forecast into a column of categorical data. The "cloud elements" can take various alphanumerical values, NaN (no cloud element in forecast) and None (cloud element given but no type). As each forecast may contain several cloud layers I wanted to store lists/arrays instead of a scalar value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `("clouds", "type", None)` column has integer dtype:

```
In [28]: df[("clouds", "type", None)].dtype
Out[28]: dtype('int64')
```

So if you want to assign NumPy arrays to this column, first change the dtype to `object`:

```
df[("clouds", "type", None)] = df[("clouds", "type", None)].astype('object')
```

---

- Use [`df.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) or `df.iat` to select or assign values to *particular cells* of a DataFrame.
- Use  `df.loc` or `df.iloc` to select or assign values to columns, rows or sub-DataFrames.

---

Therefore, use `df.at` here:

```
df[("clouds", "type", None)] = df[("clouds", "type", None)].astype('object')
for i, val in values.items():
    for j, v in val.items():
        df.at[(i, j), ("clouds", "type", None)] = np.array(v)
```

which yields a `df` that looks like

```
      clouds                         group                        
     ceiling layer          type from_date from_hours from_minutes
         NaN   NaN           NaN       NaN        NaN          NaN
0  0       0     1        [None]         3          4            5
   1       6     7             8         9         10           11
1  0      12    13        [None]        15         16           17
   1      18    19        [None]        21         22           23
   2      24    25        [None]        27         28           29
   3      30    31        [None]        33         34           35
2  0      36    37        [None]        39         40           41
   1      42    43            44        45         46           47
   2      48    49        [None]        51         52           53
3  0      54    55        [None]        57         58           59
   1      60    61        [None]        63         64           65
   2      66    67        [None]        69         70           71
   3      72    73        [None]        75         76           77
   4      78    79        [None]        81         82           83
   5      84    85        [None]        87         88           89
4  0      90    91        [None]        93         94           95
5  0      96    97            98        99        100          101
6  0     102   103  [None, None]       105        106          107
7  0     108   109           110       111        112          113
8  0     114   115           116       117        118          119
9  0     120   121  [None, None]       123        124          125
...
```

---

Regarding [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53262460/pandas-loc-function-refers-to-different-row-when-writing-vs-reading-valueerr/53263391?noredirect=1#comment93417291_53263391) that you wish to use the cloud/type column for categorical data:

Columns with categorical data must contain *hashable* values. Generally, it does not make sense to make mutable objects hashable. So, for instance, Python mutable builtins (such as lists), or NumPy arrays are not hashable. But Python immutable builtins (such as tuples) are hashable. Therefore, if you use

```
df.at[(i, j), ("clouds", "type", None)] = tuple(v)
```

then you can make the `("clouds", "type", None)` column of `category` dtype:

```
df[("clouds", "type", None)] = df[("clouds", "type", None)].astype('object')
for i, val in values.items():
    for j, v in val.items():
        df.at[(i, j), ("clouds", "type", None)] = tuple(v)

df[("clouds", "type", None)] = df[("clouds", "type", None)].astype('category')
```

Notice that it is necessary to first make the column of `object` dtype so that it may contain Python objects such as tuples, and then convert to `category` dtype only after all the possible values have been assigned.

---

Depending on what you want to do with the data, it might also make more sense to ["tidy" the data](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) by assigning only strings to the clouds/type column and using multiple rows instead of tuples:

For example,

```
6  0     102   103  'foo'       105        106          107
6  0     102   103  'bar'       105        106          107
```

instead of

```
6  0     102   103  ('foo', 'bar')       105        106          107
```

One advantage of using multiple rows is that selecting all rows with cloud/type
'foo' is now easy:

```
df.loc[df[("clouds", "type", None)] == 'foo']
```

or to select all rows with `foo` or `bar` cloud/type:

```
df.loc[df[("clouds", "type", None)].isin(['foo', 'bar'])]
```

If you use tuples, you would have to use something like

```
df.loc[[any(kind in item for kind in ('foo', 'bar')) 
       for item in df[("clouds", "type", None)]]]
```

Note only is this longer and harder to read, it is also slower.

One disadvantage of using multiple rows is that it create repeated data which may require greater memory usage. There may be ways around this, such as using multiple tables (and only joining them when required), but a discussion of this would be going way beyond the scope of this question.

So in summary, in general, use [tidy data](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf), use multiple rows, and keep your DataFrame dtypes simple -- use integers, floats whenever possible, 'strings' if necessary. Try to avoid using tuples, lists or NumPy arrays as DataFrame values.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works. The ultimate goal however (see my comment below original question) is to convert this into categorical data. The integer values were just filled in to help me finding the error. The usual defaul value is NaN. I assume I may have to find a different approach as it seems that it's not possible to use lists in columns of dtype "category".

Comment: There is a workaround which would require minimal change to your present code: Use tuples instead of NumPy arrays as values. Then you could convert the column to dtype `category`. (I've edited the post above with code to show how). But from a broader perspective, beware that -- depending on what you want to do with the DataFrame -- holding tuples or arrays *as values* inside a DataFrame is usually not a good idea. Using tidy data and multiple rows or multiple (joinable) DataFrames is often a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should either:

1. create one column per possible cloud layer (if order is important), or
2. use a bitmask, e.g. a column dtype of `'u8'` which has 64 bits, and you can set as many cloud types as are applicable to that row (if order doesn't matter).